# Upload and share an image on Facebook

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload an image to facebook and then "share/like" it. Due to the design of my homepage I can not share the image directly. I managed to get the image upload to my facebook account (first part). The image gets an facebook URL/object ID, that I am trying to use to "Share/like" the image on my wall. I am able to share the image manually on facebooks homepage.

I think it might have to do with one of the following things:

1. The permission is wrong for the image
2. Wrong POST query
3. Facebook will not allow this "Share/Like from Users photo-album" with the
   API

Down below here is some of the code I have tried (first part works). It is the "Share/Like" that does not work. From the facebook graph-API on photo, I can not find a reference to "Share/like" and nither from the user section.

```
<div id="jQuery">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</div>
<script>
 function ImageUploadAndLike(url,access_token) {
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos/test",
        data: {
            message: "Picture from my test Gallery",
            url: url,
            access_token: access_token,
            format: "json"
        },
        success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
           $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes",
        data: {
            object: data.id,
            access_token: access_token,
            format: "json"
        },
        success: function(data){
           console.log(data);}  


        })
}

            })  


        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that what ever I upload to Facebook has "Private" as the standart permission. This is default setting for my Facebook-App. As I changed that to "public" uploaded images are posted to the wall, though still without comments. As for the jQuery/JS, there is no need to first upload and then "like/share" since it gets to the wall with the correct app-setting in facebook.

Søren